# Composition $\left(f \circ g, g \circ f \right)$ of piecewise functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition, piecewise-continuity

I'm trying to solve this problem from my homework a few hours now, 
I know how to do composition for regular functions, but can't seem to understand the composition of piecewise functions.

I have checked other solutions here, but didn't get it.

Here is the problem:
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+1,  & \text{if $x<0$} \\
3x+4, & \text{if $x\ge0$}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
g(x) =
\begin{cases}
3x+2,  & \text{if $x<3$} \\
5x-8, & \text{if $x\ge3$}
\end{cases}
$$
find  $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$?
thanks :)

Comment: [A general method for your reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944925/general-method-for-composition-of-piecewise-defined-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @Rohan thank you, i've tried to figure out this general method but didn't quite make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is step-by-step hints to do it:

1. For the composition of $f(g(x))$, focus on $g(x)$ first, it has a range of $\mathbb R$ and since $f(x)$ has a domain of $\mathbb R$ too, everything is well.
2. You see that $f(x)$ is a piecewise function with two parts for $x<0$ and $x\ge0$, so you need to solve these inequalities by substituting x with $g(x)$. Now you realize that the composite function has four pieces, with domains determined by solving:
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   3x+2<0\\
   x<3
   \end{cases}
   $$
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   3x+2\ge0\\
   x<3
   \end{cases}
   $$
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   5x-8<0\\
   x\ge3
   \end{cases}
   $$
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   5x-8\ge0\\
   x\ge3
   \end{cases}
   $$
3. Finally, put each piece of $g(x)$ into $f(x)$, simplify the expression, and write down the domains that you just found in step 2 for each piece.
   $$
   f(g(x))=
   \begin{cases}
   (3x+2)+1, \ ...\\
   3(3x+2)+4, \ ...\\
   (5x-8)+1, \ ...\\
   3(5x-8)+4, \ ...\\
   \end{cases}
   $$

Then you have it! In the same way you can find $g(f(x))$ without much effort.

Comment: thank you for your quick and detailed answer, just one thing that I didn't understand is why in step 2 we check x<3 for 4 times?

Comment: Oh sorry, typo... How careless I am! Will edit that...

Comment: thank you very much, I think i solved it.

Comment: No problem. It would be great if you manually accept my answer on this page. So short on reputation now :P

Comment: Upvote from me! (also upvoted some other things) It is hard to start with not much reputation.

Comment: I really appreciated your upvote! Let's keep working hard and helping more people with maths. :D

Comment: +1 I remember being new once. Just gotta post lots and lots of (good) answers